# Excel formatting done with MVC doesnt allow date filtering in Excel

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, excel, date

I have had a look round for a similar query to this one and cant find it anywhere.

Have an excel file created via XML SpreadSheet, managed to get it all nicely formatted.

Open up said created xls file with Excel and check the formatting... looks all neat, except for dates.

If a person enters a date into an Excel cell say 14/07/2013, it is right aligned and that is fine and formatted as a date *14/07/2013.

If a program creates the dates and puts them all in Excel, they are all left aligned and formatted as a date *14/07/2013.

The Excel file created by a person can be sorted ascending or descending on the date and works as usual earliest to latest.

The Excel file created by the program can be sorted ascending or descending on the date and works by sorting on the days only???

Only way to fix the dates created by the program that I have found is for someone to go into each cell of the offending dates and press enter, excel then aligns them to the RHS of the cell and the asc/dsc searching works fine.

Is there anyway to fix this so that I dont have to get a human being (not a macro) to go in and manually 'touch' all the date rows?

XLS file is created by using XML spreadsheet in MVC application and after obtaining the data off DB its streamed out as a XLS file.

Format of dates is done via partial view:

```
<ss:Style ss:ID="MyDate">
<NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
</ss:Style>
```

So is there a fix or is this a 'feature' of excel 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the column, choose Data, Text to Columns, and then click Finish without making any choices. Based on your description, that should transform the values. If it doesn't, launch the Text to Columns wizard again, but this time go to step 3 of the Text to Columns wizard choose Date, and choose a date format that matches the month day year order that corresponds to the dates in the cells.

Comment: Was wanting to do it with out the user involvement, lets just say they are not the sharpest tool in the box period.